# Limit of $A^k b$ for $k$ large

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My textbook references the fact that for any matrix $A$ and any non-zero $b$ we have $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} A^k b = v$$ Where $v$ is the eigenvector of $A$ with the largest eigenvalue. The proof isn't obvious to me, could someone give a hint how to prove this?

Comment: You need some sort of normalization, else the quantity on the left will blow up or decay.

Comment: What if $v$ is not unique? (I.e. if multiple eigenvalues have maximal norm?)

Comment: You will want to look up the *power method* in any nice book on numerical linear algebra.

Comment: @J.M. Thank-you, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Ｊ.Ｍ. Please consider expanding your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).